# Create my own panel plugin - Xubuntu

Tags: xubuntu, xfce, gtk, plugins, temperature

I've installed Xubuntu 14.04.

In my panel I can add a lot of plugins. For example that show CPU load and RAM usage... But what about the temperature of each core?

I've found the files that contains the data about the temperature of each core: `/sys/bus/platform/devices/coretemp.0/hwmon/hwmon0` and I want to create my own plugin.

Googling it I've found a [tutorial](http://zetcode.com/tutorials/gtktutorial/) about GTK+: it seems too difficult so I tried to find the source code of an existing panel widget to modify it.

I searched for the `System Load Monitor` source code, but all I found is [this](https://launchpad.net/xfce4-systemload-plugin), without any source code.

Where can I download the source code of an existing plugin? There is a easy way to create an Xubuntu panel plugin?

Thanks a lot.

EDIT: What is a panel plugin? These are panel plugins:

[image: panel plugins example]

Comment: So you want a plugin or create your own plugin that displays your procesors temperature? Pretty sure psensor displays the temperature.

Comment: did you check [this](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/trusty/+source/xfce4-systemload-plugin)? or it's a different from what you're looking?

Comment: Yes, but can I leave `psensor` on the desktop panel, like a plugin and not like a window?

Comment: I see you want to create a kind of a desktop widget?

Comment: I think it is called Panel Plugin

Comment: well there are [panel plugins (indicators)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/30334/what-application-indicators-are-available) and desktop widgets I prefer to call them so ;)

Comment: I modified one on my own with [conky-manager](http://linuxg.net/how-to-install-conky-manager-2-3-1-on-ubuntu-14-10-ubuntu-14-04-ubuntu-12-04-and-derivative-systems/) how to [configure](http://www.wikihow.com/Configure-Conky) conky.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24602/discussion-between-xpino-and-joker).

Answer (score 5):

As for creating a new panel plugin for Xfce, see https://wiki.xfce.org/dev/howto/panel_plugins
and
https://ecc-comp.blogspot.fi/2015/02/a-simple-tutorial-for-xfce-panel-plugin.html?m=1

Answer (score 3):

I also was looking for a panel plugin that shows the temperature of the CPU in Xubuntu 16.04. By default there is no such plugin installed. I found `xfce4-sensors-plugin` which was exactly what I was looking for.

I installed it by running the command:

```
sudo apt-get install xfce4-sensors-plugin
```

After that I could find Sensor plugin in the dialog to add a panel item.

To get the source code I ran:

```
sudo apt-get source xfce4-sensors-plugin
```

Comment: As we can see in https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xfce4-sensors-plugin this package is also available for 14.04.